# IE load indicator and links with images

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, indicator, activity-indicator

Here is an example of a strange behavior with a load indicator in IE8-9 (which is on a tab)

http://afternoon-river-5822.herokuapp.com/

There are two links: the first opens a "fast" page, another - a "slow" one as if there are some calculations on it. It opens in about 20 sec.

These links have two images. The first is for default state, the second one is for highlighted.

The problem is: If click on the "slow" link in IE8-9 and move away the mouse from the link then IE will stop progress - a spinner on the tab will disappear. And in about 20 sec a new page will be displayed. But if after clicking on the link do not touch a mouse (image **will not** be changed to default) then the indicator will work correctly - will spin until a new page loads completely.

How can I avoid this behavior?

CSS:

```
.b-mainmenu li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  min-width: 58px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: -6px;
}

.b-mainmenu li a {
  display: block;
  font: bold 11px "Lucida Grande",tahoma,arial,sans-serif;
  color: #5d5e5b;
  min-width: 58px;
  padding-top: 36px;
  background-position: 50% 3px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.b-mainmenu li a:hover, 
.b-mainmenu li.active a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

a {
  display: block; width: 341px; height: 97px;
}
.b-mainmenu-fast {
  background-image: url(/assets/menu-home.png);
}
.b-mainmenu-slow {
  background-image: url(/assets/menu-backup.png);
}
.b-mainmenu-fast:hover {
  background-image: url(/assets/menu-home_aa.png);
}
.b-mainmenu-slow:hover {
  background-image: url(/assets/menu-backup_aa.png);
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="b-mainmenu">

<li><a class="b-mainmenu-fast" href="page/fast_page">Fast page</a></li>
<li><a class="b-mainmenu-slow" href="page/slow_page">Slow page</a></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can avoid changing URL related properties in hover? Instead, set `background-color` and other propoperies to achieve desired visual effect. Without URL change, load indicator will work fine. I've checked if data url would made any difference - unfortunately not.

You expect that loading new page will take a lot of time, in that case I would recommend showing some progress indicator and not care so much about build-in spinner on a tab. You can change image background for some animated gif when user clicks the link.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use colors instead images. This is only an example. The real page has a real complicated icons except these simple images. So there should be images.


It's also impossible to use JS any spinners because only built-in one.